# convert timezone identifier to name? (Asia/Calcutta to Indian Standard Time)

Tags: php, timezone

I am working on a php (codeigniter) project. I have been doing a lot of work in timezones to convert times between different timezones and the server timezone.

I know how to convert a php timezone identifier to its abbreviation (like Asia/Calcutta to IST). But now, I need the expansion of this abbreviation (Indian Standard Time).

Is there any way to do this in php code, or any webservice to convert it? This is my last step in complete mastery in timezone programming! :)

Edit: As one person who answered pointed out, abbreviations can be ambiguous.. But timezone identifiers aren't. So can I directly convert "Asia/Calcutta" to "Indian Standard Time"? There is no ambiguity in that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **@Munim**: Ahh... I didn't know about this. If that is the case, do you
>   know how to convert a timezone identifier like Asia/Calcutta to Indian
>   standard time? No ambiguity there..

Yup, (almost) no ambiguity at all. Almost because a timezone identifier might also map to several abbreviations depending on daylight savings and political changes. In PHP, you can do that with either `DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()` (but this one isn't very reliable since it shows all the abbreviations used since the dawn of tzdb) or `DateTimeZone::getTransitions()` - this one is better since if you traverse the array backwards and return the first transition `abbr` that isn't observing DST.

Answer (score 5):

You general, you can't do it because it's ambiguous -- the same abbreviation is used for differente timezones.

Example:

- CDT: Central Daylight Time (America/Cancun, America/Chicago, ...)
- CDT: Mexico Central Daylight Time (America)
- CDT: Cuba Central Daylight Time (America)
- CDT: Canada Central Daylight Time (America)

Even IST is not unique:

- IST: Irish Summer Time (Europe)
- IST: Indian Standard Time (Asia)
- IST: Israel Standard Time (not in zic)

There are, however, several heuristics. For instance, PostgreSQL comes with several timezone sets that you can swap depending on the continent of your target audience.

Comment: Ahh... I didn't know about this. If that is the case, do you know how to convert a timezone identifier like Asia/Calcutta to Indian standard time? No ambiguity there..

Comment: @Munim I don't know if you can do it just with PHP. There seems to be no way to format a date so as to get a timezone abbreviation (the closest thing is the "tz" formatter, but that will give the full timezone if possible).

Comment: If the data is not there in any php functions, I am willing to use a web service.

Comment: @Artefacto
http://www.healthstream.com/hlchelp/Administrator/Classes/HLC_Time_Zone_Abbreviations.htm
Please check the link
Israel Standard Time (ISST)
Indian Standard Time(IST)

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-to-one mapping between timezone abbreviations, timezone offsets and timezone expansions.  For example, `CDT` stands for `Central Daylight Time` which maps to both `UTC+10:30` (Australia) and `UTC-5` (North America).  It has the same abbreviation, but maps to different continents and time offsets.

Similarly, `CST` is `Central Standard Time` and `Central Summer Time` and maps onto the following 3 offsets: `UTC+9:30`, `UTC-6` and `UTC+10:30`

`IST`, which you refer to above, is also `Irish Summer Time` and maps to `UTC+1`

So, to answer your question, nope, you can't do it.  If you really want to achieve mastery in timezone programming, read up on the ISO specifications for the same.

Comment: Read my latest edit. I have changed the question. I am still looking for a solution to convert a timezone identifier(which is unique) to the expansion directly. No ambiguity there..

Comment: There's still a problem in that expansions aren't standard, but you can get most of what you want just by looking up the tzdatabase.  Here's a link: http://code.google.com/p/tzdata/

Answer (score 0):

Maye you should look this php function timezone_name_from_abbr()