# PHP Converting GMT to IST

Tags: php

Can i convert GMT to IST in PHP without using PEAR.

Here is how i get GMT `gmdate()`, now how do i convert it to IST.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+330 minutes', 0));
```

or

```
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

first get time by

```
 $time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    // than convert it to IST by
    $time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('IST'));
```

Comment: :I've an application ,end user might be from any country but when he uses app,i want to sotre date in IST.How can i do this ?

Comment: @ram: Ask the user for his timezone of course.

Comment: @ram why? Dates are best stored in UTC and offset to local timezone only when output needed

Comment: shoudnt it be 330 minutes? (GMT+5.5)

Comment: @AlixAxel thanks for editing .... ram why you can store in utc as alin said there is no problem in this

Comment: @Ram why you wanna to this? do you only print the timestamps in IST time? if not, you making your live harder then it has to be.

Comment: @ram ram you can first get GMT time and then convert it to IST

Comment: @RAM UTC & GMT are the same: from wikipedia: Coordinated Universal Time, the basis for the world's civil time, occasionally referred to by the name of its predecessor, Greenwich Mean Time.

Comment: @ram if you store time in local timezone, you're *dying* if you need to change the local timezone.

Comment: @Rufinus exactly is looks [like](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/asia/india/time/) you are right

Comment: @NullPointer rofl same page i looked it up :)

Comment: @Rufinus lol...ist also stands for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264753/convert-timezone-identifier-to-name-asia-calcutta-to-indian-standard-time

Comment: @ram: Maybe you should start a chat. Also, your original question has been answered, but I'm gonna answer your follow up question as well: **1)** ask the user for it's exact timezone (something like `Europe/Lisbon`), **2)** convert (and save) the dates he provides you to UTC, **3)** when you need to present the dates to the user, convert it back to their timezone (from UTC of course).

Comment: @AlixAxel i think we are done ... ain't we?

Comment: @ram: You're probably echo'ing without calling `format()`...

Comment: @NullPointer: Yup, I'm gonna watch some documentary.

Comment: @ram: Yeah, the United States uses a lot... :P Anyway, if the date doesn't come from the user, then all you need to do is convert from the timezone your server runs on. You can check which one by looking at your `phpinfo()`. As for the code, it's the same (input timezone -> output timezone), you just need to change the identifier.

Comment: @ram: What is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

Answer (score 4):

Easy-peasy:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-11-04 05:04:00', new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('IST'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```