# How to convert GMT time to IST?

Tags: php, date, datetime, gmt

Here I am getting GMT Time as follow.

```
1520489880
```

Now I am getting This as

```
$myfinaldate = gmdate("d M H:i", $strtoDate);
```

So it will returns me `GMT time`. Now i want to convet it to IST(indian standard time).

where I stuck when I try

```
//Set timezone to india
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But this returns me current time not the time that I get in `strtotime`

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216185/php-converting-gmt-to-ist

Comment: Yes Obviously.. See I Updated Question.

Comment: @Sorak's answer should now take care of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the timestamp:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('d M H:i', $strToDate); // where $strToDate is 1520489880
```

Would produce the following value:

```
08 Mar 11:48
```

Comment: So no use of `gmdate("d M H:i", $strtoDate)` ??

Comment: sure, they're the same

Comment: Maybe its not same @sorak. date is that the time returned is your time zone. and  gmdate is that  the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Comment: Oh, I was referring to the use of the variable. Yeah, you need to set the timezone to Kolkata, and gmdate implicitly sets it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert GMT time to IST time using following ways :

**1.**

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+330 minutes', 0));`

**2.**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing default timezone is not such a good idea. Use `DateTime` class, any you don't need to worry about default timezone anymore...

```php
$dt = new DateTime("@$strToDate");
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/968757)</kbd>